# Navicat SQL Consol in table, set record=itself/10

Tags: mysql, sql, record, navicat

```
UPDATE `kingdom`.`monsterinfos` SET `PlusCps` = `PlusCps`/10
```

on table monsterinfos how to set all pluscps records to itself/10 on navicat console.

Comment: Do you want division or just want to store `/` in string?

Comment: No storing I want to Divide all pluscps/10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all I found it XD
its so simple

UPDATE monsterinfos SET PlusCps=PlusCps/10;